# jmeter how to conclude that web server successfully handles 1000 concurrent users

Tags: jmeter

We have a web CRUD app.
I need to load test the web app, by simulating 1000 concurrent users.
i am using jmeter, to do the load test.

```
scenario 1 :
 - user login
 - request a welcome page

Parameters : 
 Thread Group : no. of users = 100
                ramp-up period = 1
                loop = 1
```

question :

- how to i conclude that the web server is capable of accepting 1000
  concurrent users?
- if in the result tree view all the request gets
  status 200 OK means, that web server is capable of accepting 1000
  concurrent users?   or
- if i increase the concurrent users to say
  1200, then web server crashes.. will i conclude that the web server
  we are using is capable of accepting at max of < 1200 concurrent
  users.
- what are the other parameters i need to look for the load    test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude it like,

1. If you see results of all requests as 200 status for not just 1 loop but you need to run your test for **some amount of time let say 30 min or something**(duration can be decided on stability factor of server).

After some time after test starts, **if results starts converging** (you will get stable response times) **without any errors** (1% error rate is acceptable generally) then you can conclude that your web server is capable of supporting 1000 users for login reqeusts

1. You can increase users to 1200 and try again to see scalability of server (how much your server can **scale**, with same technique)
   that will give you max load your server can take. (**stress test**)
2. Very important things you should also monitor while doing these tests are, your **server utilization**. If your server is choking on resources (100% cpu, 100% memory  , or network etc) then probably you should lower the concurrent users and try again. generally system utilization should not be more than 80% on all counters.

as you are running this test for one request only i.e. login . generally results will be inaccurate. you should test with mostly used workflows which will give you precise idea.

I hope this clarifies the doubts.

Comment: So need to monitor the following results with 1000 concurrent users
 "Create workflow + Update workflow + Get workflow +  Delete workflow" result
based on the above results, we can conclude the capability of the web server.
how to measure the CPU and memory, jmeter has the monitor, but how its measure's the CPU [per core ?].

Comment: see for simplicity you can divide your workflows into groups and test individually or find mostly used workflows and test with them which is best approach.For monitoring multiple tools are present, for linux -sar is present, windows - perfmon and if you have distributed environment then probably you can use ganglia,munin,graphite etc.